# Contradictory information in current capability of open drain output for the MAX7317 IO expander

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I am looking at the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/256/MAX7317-1515902.pdf) of the MAX7317 IO expander and it is not clear to me if it can drive simultaneously 8 pins when each pin sinks 16mA. I don't have a lot of options because I need SPI.

The datasheet says:

```
P0 to P9 can be configured as open-drain, current-sink outputs rated at 20mA
maximum, or as CMOS inputs, or as open-drain outputs
```

Which I must say only makes sense to me if "or as open drain outputs" is a typo;

As well as:

[image]

Which means 16mA < 24mA and 16*8+1=129mA < 200mA so ok;

But on the other hand it also says:

[image]

And this graph that confirms this line for typical conditions:

[image]

How have they obtained the 20mA max rating? If they just tested a bunch of them and got 20mA for a few, what's the point of that really instead of a minimum current rating?

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental about the power dissipation, but 0.4V of saturation voltage (which seems to be the case) times 20mA per port is negligible. Unless this is not what the 0.4V are, in which case I don't know if I can drive directly an optocoupler with 0.5V diode recovery with this.

Comment: It is possible to drive a '595 shift register with SPI, and there are optocouplers like the H11L1 that can work with 1.6 mA. But those would be different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output voltage on the outputs is only guaranteed for sinking current of 6mA or less, so I don’t think this is a useful part for sinking 16mA per output. You would need to add buffers.

It’s guaranteed to be **less** than 20mA short circuit current with a 5V supply and at 25 degrees C, so 16mA is far from guaranteed even into a short circuit.

Maybe you can use better optocouplers. 16mA is very high LED drive if you want it to last.

Answer (score 1):

> it is not clear to me if it can drive simultaneously 8 pins when each pin sinks 16mA. I don't have a lot of options because I need SPI.

It's not a typo but a guaranteed current limit maximum on Data Ports at Vo=5V of 20 mA and a DNE limit of 24 mA.

I might drive 16 mA but not without tolerances.

SPI low speed pullup might be 10k to 5V so 0.5mA.

But with 100 pF/m twisted pair and an effective RdsOn, the expected slew rate with RC=T is implied by the Vo/Io=Ron resistance but has a current limit & tolerances.  This will control the max active slew rate dV/dt=Ic/C= V+/(Ron*C) while the passive pullup slew rate is R pullup added to achieve say 4T< bit period.

Use the **Electrical Characteristics** (with Note 1) V+=3.3V @ 25'C and not the Absolute Maximum.

Then apply your ambient environmental max temperature with a margin for self-heating using the tempco of the chip and max Pd plus nearby Pd temp rise and choose some margin for Tmax.  Then choose I max vs Tmax and see if Vo satisfies your requirement.

Port signals

If your design Tmax = 85'C for the junction temp rise in ambient , I compute the RdsOn to be 233 Ohms (nominal) for Vout < 2V / 8.6 mA (nominal). You can apply KVL to compute to your max Data Output Port for a nominal output.

e.g. Vo = 8 mA * 233 Ohms = 1.86 V nominal then Pd = 8 mA*1.86V ~ 15 mW  . It should be less current in your design.

Due to manufacturing process variables short circuit current to 5V has a wide tolerance. This means the Nch FET has a wide tolerance to Vgs(the) and RdsOn.  10.8 mA typ. 20 mA max.

### Conclusion

For SPI you will know that this IC is protected from temporary short circuit current limits to 5V by design and you will choose the pullup required for your speed to have adequate immunity and slew rate for your junction min/max temperature.